# 2-bit comparator using multiplexers only

Tags: multiplexer

I have to design comparator using multiplexers only? Here is what've done arleady.[image]

Comment: Does this help?: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/335709/comparing-and-adding-numbers-using-multiplexers-and-comparators

Comment: No its not that

Comment: Why? Sounds like "I want to make a stew using bricks only".

Comment: It's a useful exercise, especially with CMOS where the transmission gate is a fundamental building block. And a mux is essentially a bank of transmission gates. OK, really abstract and not very useful but can be enlightening

Comment: What is the question?